# how should i use android pmem or ion mermory in my app?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-device-driver, android-framework

I want to use pmem or ion my android project without root.  does there some java or c/c++ api to use?  follow is ndk code ,it should run with root.

```
    int pmem_fd = open("/dev/pmem_adsp", O_RDWR, 0); //open /dev/pmem
    if (pmem_fd>=0)
    {
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, strok);
    }
    else
    {
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, strfail);
    }
```

Comment: These are kernel services used by HALs and drivers.  Generally speaking, non-system code shouldn't be using them directly.

Comment: @Firemky That PMEM is used for communicating and transferring data between the processors on your platform.  It is shared memory.  ADSP is the signal processor.  It performs a lot of the multimedia functionality.